# Python/Pygame crash: attribute error

Tags: python, debugging, attributes, pygame

This is code for a program I am writing that is supposed to be a card game. 
 I have come across a crash, and running it through the debugger gives me an error I'm not sure I understand.  I looked it up but don't really know what it means in the context of this code, thanks for your time!

I am running this code:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import*

WINWIDTH = 1200
WINHEIGHT = 800
CARDTHUMBWIDTH = 50
CARDTHUMBHEIGHT = 80
FPS = 30
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINWIDTH,WINHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('NBA Card Game')
pygame.init()

IMAGES = {
0: pygame.image.load(playerHand[0]),
1: pygame.image.load(playerHand[1]),                         
2: pygame.image.load(playerHand[2]),
3: pygame.image.load(playerHand[3])}

RECTS = [pygame.Rect(17, 635, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(75, 635, 50, 80),
         pygame.Rect(133, 635, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(191, 635, 50, 80)]

playerHandPos = [(17, 635), (75, 635), (133, 635), (191, 635), (249, 635), (307, 635), (365, 635), (423, 635), (481, 635), (539, 635)]
lakersDeck = ['Lakers_01.png', 'Lakers_02.png', 'Lakers_03.png', 'Lakers_04.png', 'Lakers_05.png', 'Lakers_06.png', 'Lakers_07.png', 'Lakers_08.png', 'Lakers_09.png', 'Lakers_10.png']

turnCount = 0
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
userTextPrompt = "20, 725"
playMat = pygame.image.load('playmat.png')
detailBox = pygame.image.load('detailBox.png')
DISPLAYSURF.blit(playMat, (0,0))



def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, (0,0,0))
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x,y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

def getFirstHand():
    firstHand = []
    playerDeck = lakersDeck
    random.shuffle(playerDeck)
    firstHand.append(playerDeck[0])
    firstHand.append(playerDeck[1])
    firstHand.append(playerDeck[2])
    firstHand.append(playerDeck[3])
    return firstHand

def displayHand(hand):
    handCount = len(hand)
    for card in range(handCount):
        cardThumb = pygame.image.load(hand[card])
        cardThumb = pygame.transform.scale(cardThumb, (50,80))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(cardThumb, playerHandPos[card])
    pygame.display.update()

def playerTurn():
    placedBench = False
    while placedBench == False:
        drawText("Choose a card for your bench.", font, DISPLAYSURF, 20, 725)
        pygame.display.update()
        placedBench = True

def cardLakers_01():
    offense = 10
    return offense

def matchLoop():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, IMAGES, RECTS
    playerHand = []
    playerDeck = lakersDeck
    getHand = getFirstHand()
    playerHand = getHand



    for cards in range(4):
        del playerDeck[0]

    while True:
        currentImageIndex = None
        mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for i, rect in enumerate(RECTS):
            if rect.collidepoint(mousePos):
                currentImageIndex = i
                break
        if currentImageIndex is not None:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(IMAGES[currentImageIndex], RECTS[curentImageIndex])
            pygame.display.update()

        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update()

matchLoop()
pygame.display.update()
```

It crashes and when I run it through the debugger I am getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shyot/Desktop/python/Bball Card/Cards/main2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame, sys, random
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 148, in __enter__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 174, in _get_module_lock
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 59, in __init__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 59, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\shyot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\bdb.py", line 48, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "C:\Users\shyot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\bdb.py", line 66, in dispatch_line
    self.user_line(frame)
  File "C:\Users\shyot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\idlelib\debugger.py", line 24, in user_line
    self.gui.interaction(message, frame)
AttributeError: '_ModuleLock' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, thanks for your help!

edit: not sure why, but now it's saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shyot/Desktop/python/Bball Card/Cards/main2.py", line 17, in <module>
    0: pygame.image.load(playerHand[0]),
NameError: name 'playerHand' is not defined
```

Comment: Just as a troubleshooting measure, could you split your three imports into three different lines so we can see more clearly which package is causing the problem?

Comment: It runs fine on my computer.

Comment: @Niayesh I split the imports at the top and got the same exact issue, how did you want me to present this?  Not really sure

Comment: @Coder22 that's so strange, it doesn't run correctly for me

Comment: @immeeh you load images like this: `image=pygame.image.load('image_name')`

Answer (score 0):

One reason why your game crashes is that you don't handle the events each frame and the operating system assumes the game has become unresponsive. You have to call one of the [`pygame.event`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) functions , for example `pygame.event.get()`, each frame, or at least call `pygame.event.pump()`.

In the lines 15-18 you're using a variable `playerHand` that hasn't been defined before, so you're getting a `NameError`. You're defining a `playerHand` variable in the `matchLoop` function, but it is local to this function and can't be used outside.

You need to restructure some parts of your code. I'd load the images first, then create the random `playerHand` and afterwards the `images` dictionary. Here's a complete example:

```
import random
import pygame


pygame.init()
WINWIDTH = 1200
WINHEIGHT = 800
FPS = 30
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINWIDTH, WINHEIGHT))

# Load the images. 
LAKERS_IMAGES = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    LAKERS_IMAGES.append(pygame.image.load('Lakers_{:02}.png'.format(i)).convert())

RECTS = [pygame.Rect(17, 135, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(75, 135, 50, 80),
         pygame.Rect(133, 135, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(191, 135, 50, 80)]


def matchLoop():
    playerDeck = LAKERS_IMAGES.copy()  # Don't modify the original list.
    random.shuffle(playerDeck)
    # First 4 cards are the hand, the rest is the remaining deck.
    playerHand, playerDeck = playerDeck[:4], playerDeck[4:]
    images = {
        0: playerHand[0],
        1: playerHand[1],
        2: playerHand[2],
        3: playerHand[3],
        }

    done = False

    while not done:
        # Handle events each frame or the game will crash.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

        # Game logic.
        currentImageIndex = None
        mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for i, rect in enumerate(RECTS):
            if rect.collidepoint(mousePos):
                currentImageIndex = i
                break

        # Draw everything.
        DISPLAYSURF.fill((0, 50, 50))
        for rect in RECTS:
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, (0, 100, 140), rect, 2)
        if currentImageIndex is not None:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(images[currentImageIndex], RECTS[currentImageIndex])

        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update() # Update the display only once per frame.


matchLoop()
pygame.quit()
```

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, so the card drawing code could maybe still be improved.

If you don't know how the string formatting (`str.format` method) works, check out [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/#number_padding).

Comment: BTW, please don't delete your questions, otherwise people with similar problems will have to ask again.